# iPhone web applications apple-touch-startup-image

Tags: html, iphone, iphone-web-app

How to stop device orientation when splash screen is shown for iphone web app .

Comment: What does that mean exactly? Do you want to ignore device orientation when showing your app (i.e. force landscape or portrait)?

Comment: Yes I want to ignore device orientation for splash screen.